# Qlik - How to get list of assigned Space / Fetch all Apps of an Space / Fetch all Sheets of an App using REST API

Tags: embed, qlikview, qliksense

I am working on a project, where I integrated Qlik by embedding the Qlik Apps and Sheets on my website. So the flow of my website is like below:

1. User visit my site, logged in and authenticate with his Qlik account using OAuth, so I have the JWT token of the user.
2. User first select a Space from the dropdown, this list generated using the API: [Space REST](https://qlik.dev/apis/rest/spaces/).
3. Then user select an App from another dropdown. These Apps are of previously selected Space and generated using the API: [Apps REST](https://qlik.dev/apis/rest/apps/).
4. Now the user select a Sheet from another dropdown. These Sheets are of previously selected App and generated using the JS code: [Handle sheets in iframes with enigma.js](https://qlik.dev/embed/iframe/customize/handle-sheets-in-iframes-with-enigma/).
5. When user select a Sheet, and click on the 'Load' button, then the related Sheet will render on the website.

It is working but there are some challenges, please check below points for query/issues:

1. When I tried to list the Spaces, all of the Spaces are returning from the API. However on the Qlik I can see all these Spaces, but my Qlik user not assigned/selected in these Spaces. So basically I need only those Spaces where the logged in user is directly assigned/selected. Is it possible to do?
2. I am able to view all these Spaces and Apps on the Qlik, but when I tried to embed them then it is not working. I can embed only those Apps where I am assigned in their Spaces.
   Following is the error I caught when tried to embed other Apps where I am not assigned in their Space.

[image]

3. Same issue with the Apps also. I need the all Apps of the selected Space only. So is there any filter available for the Apps by Space?
4. Currently I am using JS code to list Sheet by App. So is there any API available to list all Sheets of an App?

Also for the embedding part, I used following 2 article/question from Qlik community, may be helpful for someone:

1. [Embedding Qlik Cloud Content with JWT Authentication](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Member-Articles/Enhanced-Guide-Embedding-Qlik-Cloud-Content-with-JWT/tac-p/2433942)
2. [How to embed Qlik App/Sheet on the website](https://community.qlik.com/t5/Integration-Extension-APIs/How-to-embed-Qlik-App-Sheet-on-the-website/td-p/2423034)

Can anyone please help me on this or please suggest something to troubleshoot.

Thank You...